# Is the phrase “alles senkrecht” a sexual innuendo?

Tags: etymology, phrase

I am startled whenever I hear the phrase “Alles senkrecht?”, meaning “how’s it going?” I think that’s because I consider it very vulgar (with *senkrecht* referring to penis position).

Does the phrase have this sexual origin?

Comment: I would be pretty sure it does.

Comment: No, I don't believe this. Until now this connection never came in my mind when I heard or used this phrase.

Comment: As a women I woulnd never ever asked a guy _Na, alles senkrecht?_ to start a conversation. It might not have a sexual notion at the origin, but nowadays it can be easily misinterpreted as bad-style-flirting.

Comment: I don't mean to be kink shaming, but *senk-* as well as *lot-recht* refers to pendicular position, ie. hanging straight as a rope, unlike a like a metal bar that could plow a frozen aker (there that's a proper inuendo, and a popular one due to TV)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Es gibt den Ausdruck

> Alles im Lot

welcher wohl bedeutet, dass Handwerker ihre Arbeit erfolgreich und genau vollbracht haben. Diese verwenden ein Lot, ein Senkblei oder eine Wasserwaage, um zu prüfen, ob alles, was senkrecht sein soll, senkrecht geworden ist.

Im Gegensatz dazu steht ein anatomisch wohlgeformter Penis in Erwartung großer Verzückung zwar aufrecht, aber kaum senkrecht.

Comment: Ich sehe das aus so, dass die Phrasen »alles im Lot« und »alles senkrecht« als Synonyme verwendet werden, und dass sich »alles senkrecht« aus »alles im Lot« entwickelt hat.

Comment: Just for the record: I've heard "alles senkrecht in der Hose" used once or twice, so I'm not the only one making that connection.

Comment: @user134593: Es gibt auch Person aus jedem gehörten "Ich komme" eine anzügliche Bemerkung machen. Das heißt aber nicht, dass der Ursprung des Wortes von Orgasmus herkommt.

Comment: Es gibt durchaus beeindruckende Phallusdarstellungen, bei denen die Haltung im Schneidersitz eine senkrechte Pose des Phallus bewirkt, sodass es ein bischen so aussieht, als stünde das Gerät selbstständig zwischen den überschlagenen Beinen wie eine Säule, die gen Himmel ragt, unumstößlich, wie ein Angebot, das der geneigte Betrachter kaum ausschlagen dürfte. Übrigens frage ich mich grad, ob *senk-* ggf. zu *sankt* anstatt *sinken* zu stellen wäre, aber das ist sakrileg.

Answer (score 5):

Als Deutscher kann ich dir versichern, dass dieser Ausdruck (normalerweise) keinen sexuellen Hintergrund hat. 
Es ist eher ein "conversation-starter", also eine rhetorische Frage, auf die dein Gegenüber wenn nur eine kurze, nicht wirklich ernst gemeinte Antwort erwartet.

Comment: Als Frau würde ich NIEMALS einen Mann mit "Na, alles senkrecht?" ansprechen. Das schreit nach einer schlechten Anmache.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard this phrase, but I assume it originates from the usage of a [spirit level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_level). There is also the phrase "Alles waagerecht?" which seems also relate to the level interpretation.

If "everything is in level" then "everything is okay", or "fine"

Comment: Now I for my part have never heard *alles waagrecht?*

Comment: Just found that out by googling

Comment: @Jan: I never heard _Alles senkrecht_ before, either …

Comment: What is a spirit level?

Comment: @CarstenS Wasserwaage.

Comment: @PaulFrost, thank you, somehow this expression was so confusing to me that I did not even think of looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

You might be surprised to find that *recht, errect, correct*, and many more words are cognate. With words like *just* ~ *justified* (Lat. *ius* "law") this isn't limited to a single family of words either. So I suggest that the phrase simply plays on the positive connotations of *recht* augmented with an arbitrary, collocated attribute. As was already pointed out, *alles im Lot* exists as well, and I should add for contrast eg. *der Haussegen hängt Schief* (which I imagine refered initially to motto samplers at the entrance, which may bear a *Segnung* or other kind of set phrase).

However, with phrases like *alles fit im Schritt* you would be quite correct.